# android 11: Record call audio

Tags: android

I have below code that record call audio:

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

This code work on android 10 and older but in android 11 don't work and occur this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
```

I have below permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```